# Keep text aligned vertically on a Checkbox Input

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I want to keep my text aligned vertically on a checkbox input, but when larger labels are added the text will drop a line, ending up below the checkbox.

See screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/hb7ow2

Is there any way to keep the text aligned as shown in the second screenshot?

Comment: Show us a code and not a photo

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of a fairly recent question, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You are quite the artist man - don't give up on the dream!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, for future reference for anyone reading this: target the checkbox (I used :before), position as absolute, position accordingly, wrap label in a span tag, add a margin-left, finally add spacing to your suiting.